# Require an Array to be a minimum size in Swift-protocol

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, protocols, type-constraints

I have an object that will output pixels line by line (just like old televisions did). This object simply writes bytes into a twodimensional array. So there is a number of horizontal lines with each having a number of pixels. These numbers are fixed: there is x number of horizontal lines, and each lines y number of pixels. A pixel is a struct of red, green, blue.

I would like clients of this class to plug in their own object to which these values can be written, as I would like this code two work well on Apple-platforms (where CALayer is present), but also on other platforms (e.g. Linux, where the rendering needs to be done without CALayer). So I was thinking of making protocols like this:

```
struct Pixel
{
    var red: UInt8 = 0
    var green: UInt8 = 0
    var blue: UInt8 = 0
}
protocol PixelLine
{
    var pixels: [Pixel] { get }
}
protocol OutputReceivable
{
    var pixelLines: [PixelLine] { get }
}
```

These protocols woul be used at some point like

```
let pixelLineIndex = ... // max 719
let pixelIndex = ... // max 1279

// outputReceivable is an object that conforms to the OutputReceivable protocol
outputReceivale.pixelLines[pixelLineIndex][pixelIndex].red = 12
outputReceivale.pixelLines[pixelLineIndex][pixelIndex].green = 128
outputReceivale.pixelLines[pixelLineIndex][pixelIndex].blue = 66
```

Two questions arise:

- how to require the protocol PixelLine to have a minimum of 1280 Pixel units in the array and  and the protocol OutputReceivable a minimum of 720 PixelLine elements in the array ?
- as I learned from [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gr6HXCQ9tX8), using generics can help the compiler generate optimal code. Is there a way for me to use generics to generate more performant code then using plain protocols as a type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no dependent types in Swift. You cannot directly require Arrays to be of a minimum size. What you can do is create new types that can only be constructed with particular data. So in this case, the better model would be to make `PixelLine` a struct rather than a protocol. Then you can have an `init?` that ensures that it is legal before using it.

A simple struct wrapper around an Array is zero-cost in memory and extremely low cost in dispatch. If you're dealing with a high performance system, a struct wrapping an Array is an excellent starting point.

```
struct PixelLine {
    let pixels: [Pixel]
    init?(pixels: [Pixel]) {
        guard pixels.count >= 1280 else { return nil }
        self.pixels = pixels
    }
}
```

You can either expose `pixels` directly like this does, or you can make `PixelLine` a Collection (or even just a Sequence) that forwards its required methods to `pixels`.

Comment: This option had occurred to me, but this way clients would not be able to plug there own instance into my pixel-outputter object. Using your suggestion, the pixel-outputted would be the one vending the output-instance, making it less efficient to do conversions on the client side (e.g. inverted coordinate space, different color space, scaling, transforming, etc). I would like the clients of this class to allow this conversion right when a value gets set.

Comment: By the way, any thoughts on when you would use `guard pixels.count >= 1280 ...` versus `precondition(pixels.count == 1280) ...`?

Comment: The way you're a envisioning it is not possible in Swift (or any mainstream language I'm aware of; it's called dependent types and is generally a research topic in language design). Your best tool is to wrap Line in a concrete type (struct) rather than a protocol. It can accept a Collection rather than an Array to give the caller more flexibility. An init? is generally better than a precondition if you're reading from a file/network. A precondition is better if caller is expected to have generated data in code. Depends on use case. But can't be solved at compile time in Swift.

Comment: Coming up to 5 years since I asked... I went with your approach all this time, so accepting your answer. Apologies for my negligence of giving credit where due.